# Get current PID in Slot (if available) while in TYPO3-Backend

Tags: typo3

Via `SignalSlotDispatcher` I connected my Slot to some signal (`SIGNAL_PreFileAdd`) which typically fires in the backend after a file upload.

In that slot I now want to access the page ts config to determine some extension configuration.

I am aware that there will only be page ts config if the user is either in the web module or the frontend but that's okay. For example, in the file list there will not be page ts config because no page is selected. But if the user uploads content via element browser in some content element, then there will be accessible page ts config.

I know that I can get the page ts config via `BackendUtility::getPagesTSconfig($pid)` but that requires knowledge of the `$pid`. So ultimately the question is: How can I determine the current page id if it is available? (i.e. fe or web module)

This question is of course about TYPO3 7.6+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only clean way to get the current page id in the backend seems to be taking the currently handled record's `pid` (or `uid` if it is the page itself).

This is also the way the core does it.

While it is hard to achieve in the context of slots, it can easily be done in the `processUpload_postProcessAction` hook for example:

```php
public function processUpload_postProcessAction(&$filename, DataHandler $pObj) {
    $pid = $pObj->checkValue_currentRecord['pid'];
    GeneralUtility::devLog(
        'pid',
        'exampleext',
        GeneralUtility::SYSLOG_SEVERITY_INFO,
        [$pid]
    );
}
```